# Rspec how to checks the value present in the an another method which that method doesn't return anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi i have written Rspec to validate a body of message\n

```
 describe "validate_msm" do

  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  it "should contains welcome user" do 
    body = user.send_sms("909090990")
    expect(body).to include("welcome")
  end
end
```

as send_sms will call the send method which i have mentioned in let!

```
def send_sms

...

..

  body="welcome user"

  Message.send(contact, body)

end
```

so how to check with the body content is equal to welcome user ,
as send_sms doesn't return anything, so how to checks the value present in the body variable in rspec

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Or rather you don't that easily. Most of the libraries like this should come together with test adapters and helpers to make such testing possible. If this one does not, you can only test that the message has been sent with correct arguments:

```
it "should contains welcome user" do
  allow(Message).to receive(:send)
  
  user.send_sms("909090990")
  
  expect(Message).to have_received(:send) do |_contact, body|
    expect(body).to include "welcome"
  end
end
```